# Multiply function with 1 argument only

Tags: javascript, multiplication

I have a javascript coding exercise to do which has got me a bit stuck (I'm only just starting javascript).

The exercise is as follows:

Write a function multiply(a) that returns a function capable of multiplying by a. Call this function with b as a parameter.

So far I have the main skeleton (not difficult):

```
function multiply(a) {
    return //Stuck here
}
```

I'm not sure if the question is to call multiply(b) and have it give us the result of a*b or something else...

I tried writing a function directly after the return statement but this just printed out the function name.

```
function multiply(a) {
    return function f { return a * b } //Here I assume b is a variable defined somewhere
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Close `Here I assume b is a variable defined somewhere` You have to define `b` as the argument. (the syntax error that your `f` does not have an argument list could be a hint :) )

Comment: @CertainPerformance I feel the point of the exercise is to only have a as an argument, not a and b if you see what I mean.

Comment: Right, `b` should be the argument to the *returned* function. Both functions take only one argument

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks, could be the answer :D

Answer (score 0):

You could take a closure over the variable and return a function for the multiplication for the multiplicand.

```js
function multiply(a) {
    return function (b) { 
        return a * b;
    }
}

var threeTimes = multiply(3);

console.log(threeTimes(7));
```

Comment: Thanks, I feel this could be it!